# How to get Docker to retry image pull?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, nomad

Our Nomad agents sometimes fails jobs because they cannot pull images from ECR. /var/log/docker will contain messages like:

> Not continuing with pull after error: error pulling image
>   configuration: Get
>   https://prod-eu-west-1-starport-layer-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uuid/uuid?...:
>   dial tcp IP:443: i/o timeout

The jobs are not really idempotent, so I would prefer not to have Nomad retry them.

Is there any way I can instruct Docker to retry these operations?

Comment: Nomad should just give it a retry after some seconds/minutes.